# Hangfire missing Schedule jobs after decreasing the servers number

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am having Hangfire with ASP.NET Application running on Docker swarm, sometimes I need to change the instances count of the Hangfire servers. when I increase the number there is no any problem, but when I decrease the number of the insurances, Hangfire is missing all the scheduled jobs. to fix this I should restart all the running instances. Any config or settings should I add for the Hangfire server to reschedule the scheduled jobs automatically after a period or after the servers instances number changed. our config now:

```
services.AddHangfireServer(jobServerOptions =>
                    {                        
                        jobServerOptions.Queues = QueueHelper.GetQueuesNames().ToArray();
                        jobServerOptions.WorkerCount = backgroundJobConfig.GetValue<int?>("WorkerCount") ?? 2;
                    });
```

I tried to add an API to call it manually to reschedule the scheduled jobs.

Comment: What kind of storage are you using for hangfire in your docker swarm ?

Comment: I am using Sql server

Comment: Have you checked in the database that, when you decrease the number of servers, the scheduled jobds disappear ? Please show the complete code setting up hangfire `services.AddHangfire(configuration => ...).`